# Repeat the function

Tags: xcode, function, loops, timer, swift3

I'm trying to repeat this function so it just keeps on repeating until someone stops it on the interface but when it returns to increaseTimer(), it get's an error saying: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Please could someone help so this function keeps on looping automatically.

```
    func increaseTimer() {
    time += 1

    if time > 2 && time < 4 {
        timerLabel.text = "Hold"
    } else if (time > 5 && time < 10) {
        timerLabel.text = "Breathe out"
    } else if (time > 11 && time < 14) {
        timerLabel.text = "Hold"
    } else { return increaseTimer()}
```

Comment: Your method should not return anything and you are trying to return the method itself there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and infinitely repeat code to simulate a timer. Instead, use the `Timer` object. The code below will start a timer and call the provided closure every 1 second.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
    increaseTimer()
})
```

When you want to stop the timer, call `invalidate()`.

```
timer.invalidate()
```

In order to alternate between the messages, do something like this:

```
func updateMessage() {

    time += 1

    switch time {
    case 0 ... 5:
        timerLabel.text = "Hold"
    case 6 ... 10:
        timerLabel.text = "Breathe Out"
    default:
        time = 0
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, here's the part of the code I'm working on in the timer section. I tried to change this so it's like your comment above but having trouble making it repeat:    {
        timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController3.increaseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

Comment: That looks like it should work. Did you modify the `increaseTimer` function so that it doesn't return a call to itself?

Comment: Yes I modified that and it works but what I'm trying to do is get it so the timerlabel.text repeats whole function automatically and does not stop. Do u know how I would do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's seems like you want to change a label after a certain number of seconds has passed, which is what my solution will do since it will call your update code every second.

Comment: That's right but it doesn't loop after: else if (time > 11 && time < 14) {timerLabel.text = "Hold" }

Comment: I just want it to keep looping around automatically without stopping. How could I do that?

Comment: Do you want to reset the `time` to `0` so that it always alternates between your two messages?

Comment: Yes, how would you do that?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, feel free to mark it as correct so others can benefit in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could always reset the time Int every time you need to repeat your code block.Like so:

First I would declare my timer and set it's initial value to 0.

```
var timer : Timer = 0
```

then place the following wherever you want to start your timer. (either in an @IBAction or wherever)

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateMessage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then place the code to reset your time variable within your switch statement. (I would set it to 1 as this would be on the 11th second)

```
func updateMessage() {

    time += 1

    switch time {
    case 1 ... 5:
        timerLabel.text = "Hold"
    case 6 ... 10:
        timerLabel.text = "Breathe Out"
        time = 0
    case 11:
        timerLabel.text = "Hold"
//Reset the time Int to start the loop again
        time = 1
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Be sure to invalidate your timer when you don't need it anymore.

```
timer.invalidate()
```